# SQL - select only latest record for each foreign key

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Hello so my problem is basically, I have a table **files** like so:

| foreign_key | string | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "a" | 2021-11-10 |
| 2 | "b" | 2021-11-15 |
| 2 | "c" | 2021-11-18 |

Now what I need is to select one record (string) for each distinct foreign_key and it always needs to be the **latest** (created_at)

I **can't use subquery** in selects because of speed.

The result should look like this:

| foreign_key | string | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "a" | 2021-11-10 |
| 2 | "c" | 2021-11-18 |

Comment: *"I can't use subquery in selects because of speed"* would you mind share that query along with the perf?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_key
                                   ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT foreign_key, string, created_at
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Another approach, using joins:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT foreign_key, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY foreign_key
) t2
    ON t2.foreign_key = t1.foreign_key AND
       t2.max_created_at = t1.created_at;
```

Comment: I always refer back to the join example in this post. I normally use the primary key in place of created_at. (The amount of times it comes up for me makes me wonder why there isn't a more succinct way of doing this, but grateful for this answer nonetheless.)